# Can the results of datastream be output to List or Map?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I hope to read the ID field in the database table through a stream, store the field in the list, and then create a new stream based on this ID to filter the corresponding data and synchronize it to Hudi. code show as below，I have two ideas：

first：

```
DataStream<BatchEntity> dataStream = env.addSource(new BatchNoSource());
dataStream.map(new MapFunction<BatchEntity,Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object map(BatchEntity o) throws Exception {
        Configuration batchNoConf = new Configuration();
        batchNoConf.setInteger("batchNo",oriBatchNo);
        env.getConfig().setGlobalJobParameters(batchNoConf);
        DataStreamSource<BatchEntity> batchSource = env.addSource(new BatchSource());
        DataStream<RowData> batchRowDataDS = batchSource.map((MapFunction<BatchEntity, RowData>) value -> {
            try {
                String subNode = value.getSubNode();
                String subDate = value.getSubDate();
                GenericRowData row = new GenericRowData(14);
                row.setField(0, StringData.fromString(subNode));
                row.setField(1, StringData.fromString(subDate));
                row.setField(2, StringData.fromString(transType));
                return row;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        });
        batchBuilder.sink(batchRowDataDS, false);
        return null;
    }
});
env.execute();
```

The problem with this method is that the batchSource is a empty stream, without any content, and printing using the print method is also empty.

second：

```
DataStream<BatchEntity> dataStream = env.addSource(new BatchNoSource());
dataStream.map(new MapFunction<BatchEntity,Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object map(BatchEntity o) throws Exception {
        batchNoList.add(o.getBatchNo());
        return o.getBatchNo();
    }
});
System.out.println(batchNoList.size());
for(int oriBatchNo:batchNoList){
    batchNoConf.setInteger("batchNo",oriBatchNo);
    env.getConfig().setGlobalJobParameters(batchNoConf);
    DataStream<BatchEntity> batchSource = env.addSource(new BatchSource());
    DataStream<RowData> batchRowDataDS = batchSource.map((MapFunction<BatchEntity, RowData>) value -> {
        try {
            String subNode = value.getSubNode();
            String subDate = value.getSubDate();
            GenericRowData row = new GenericRowData(14);
            row.setField(0, StringData.fromString(subNode));
            row.setField(1, StringData.fromString(subDate));
            return row;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    });
    //batchBuilder.sink(batchRowDataDS, false);
}
env.execute();
```

The problem with this method is that batchNoList is empty and cannot go to the next step. The execution order here seems to be inconsistent with what I expected. It always executes to the for loop first, and then executes to the batchNoList.add() method. Causes batchNoList to be empty.

To sum up, is there any solution? Or is there something wrong with my code?

I have tried both methods above, but they have not been successful

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed one pipeline (the inner source, map, etc) inside of an operator of another pipeline (the outer map). This doesn't fit Flink's programming model.

What you can do is pass two different streams through the same operator -- one which is building up context and state that will be used for processing the other stream. You can achieve this pattern with a CoProcessFunction or KeyedCoProcessFunction.